# How to publish winform app in VS Community 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I had started working on Winform app in VS Studio Community 2019 and i didn't have any problems. Nowadays I have 2022 version and when I make some changes I cannot publish app. I click in menu on project/publish, then 3 times i click on Next button (everything looks identical with 2019 version), but when I click on Finish it throws me this error:

```
Failed to connect to 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\EnglishTester\' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\EnglishTester'.  Unable to create the Web site location 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\EnglishTester'.  Access denied. EnglishTester       1
```

But I don't try to publish website, but plain winform desktop aplication, so I don't understand what is going on and cannot find how to fix it.

[image]

There are screens of all publish steps:
[image]

Comment: `dotnet publish` at command prompt is much easier to go https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish

Comment: Have you installed the "ClickOnce Publishing" component (Visual Studio Installer => Modify => click "Individual components" => ClickOnce Publishing)?

Comment: @user9938 yes, i have it

Comment: Please add images to your post of the 3 dialogs that you click "Next" on.

Comment: @user9938 I have attached it now at the end of my question now.